# App generating java.lang.NullPointerException when compiled on different developer machine

Tags: android

I have an application that compiles and runs fine when run on a machine X.

We check the code out compile and run it on machine Y and it generates a null pointer exception.

The Null pointer exception is listed below the main body.

I have investigated and the code is failing when a `findViewById()` call is executed on an edit text box.

The call has an id (integer) but returns a null in the place of the view.

We have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but this does not seem to resolve the problem.

I believe the problem may some how be related to R.java identifiers being corrupted on the new install.

```
09-08 15:50:10.186 28278-28278/ca.client.crmlogon E/ACRA: ACRA caught a RuntimeException for ca.client.crmlogon
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.client.crmlogon/ca.client.crmlogon.Activities.WorkOrderActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
    at ca.client.crmlogon.Activities.GUIFormActivity.hideFieldById(GUIFormActivity.java:690)
    at ca.client.crmlogon.Activities.GUIFormActivity.hideFieldByName(GUIFormActivity.java:697)
    at ca.client.crmlogon.Activities.WorkOrderActivity.hideAgreementSection(WorkOrderActivity.java:1604)
    at ca.client.crmlogon.Activities.WorkOrderActivity.loadServiceAppointment(WorkOrderActivity.java:2026)
    at ca.client.crmlogon.Activities.WorkOrderActivity.onCreate(WorkOrderActivity.java:515)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2855)�
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)�
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)�
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)�
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)�
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)�
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)�
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)�
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)�
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: If you cleaned and rebuilt the project, then the `R.java` file should (hopefully) be generated the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be missing some files. If you transfered it using Git, make sure all your files were added before your last commit/push.

If you transfered it over a USB stick, etc. you may have accidentally removed the device before the transfer was complete.

My first suggestion is to try the transfer again, making sure you didn't miss any files.